# 'Anshei' vs 'B'nei'

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tanach, grammar-dikduk, ezra-nechemya

[Ezra 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.2) contains a big list of the size of different families. However, some of the verses (eg 16, 17, 18) introduce those they count as בני, and some of the verses (eg 22, 23, 27) introduce those they count as אנשי. Does anyone address the reason for the different terminology?